# Read uncommitted changes in SQLite

Tags: .net, sqlite

I'm trying to perform a dirty read on two separate connections using SQLite and .NET 6. I am using `System.data.SQLite`.

I read on the SQLite documentation that to achieve this the two connections need to have a shared cache and the `read_uncommitted` flag needs to be `true`.

I did both of the following in the code below but I am unable to read the uncommitted data

```
// open first connection
using var connection1 = new SQLiteConnection(Constants.connectionString + ";cache=shared");
connection1.Open();

// open transaction and insert some rows
using var transaction1 = connection1.BeginTransaction();
for (int i = 0; i < Constants.iterations; i++)
{
    using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand($@"insert into {Constants.tableName} (Description) values ('test')", connection1);
    _ = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}

// open second connection
using var connection2 = new SQLiteConnection(Constants.connectionString + ";cache=shared");
connection2.Open();

// set read_uncommitted to true
using var cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand($"pragma read_uncommitted=true", connection2);
cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

using var cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand($"select * from {Constants.tableName}", connection2);
cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
```

I tried setting the `read_uncommitted` flag in the connection string but it still isn't working.

If I commit the transaction the second connection is obviously able to read the new data, since it has been committed, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. How can I read the uncommitted data?

Comment: `Dirty read` means exactly the same as `read uncommitted`. Why do you want that in the first place? There's seldom a good reason to read uncommitted changes, in any database or scenario.

Comment: As for the shared cache mode [it's obsolete](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) and only meant for in-memory DBs. You need to enable the WAL mode to have two connections to the same SQLite database in the first place. With WAL, the uncommitted changes may not even be in the database yet. With WAL, changes from different connections are written to a Write Ahead Log and applied to the database later. SQLite isn't a server based database though. It's hosted and run by your own application. It may take time until changes are even written to the database.

Comment: So once again, why do you want dirty reads? What do you want to read? It may not be in the database at all

Comment: I am migrating my project from SQL server to SQLite. I am testing the features of SQLite to make sure it can fulfill my needs. There are several situations where I need to perform a dirty read and with SQL server I can do that without trouble. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Wal mode is enabled in my database and I understand what you are saying, reading from the documentation a checkpoint is either done automatically or after a commit.
With that said, I still need to find a way to read uncommitted data. I was expecting SQLite to automatically manage the wal file, since both shared cache and read_uncommitted are enabled.

Comment: `There are several situations where I need to perform a dirty read and with SQL server I can do that without trouble.` no there aren't and you can't. You may have ignored the problems or covered them up, but they're there. Just because you avoided or covered up critical bugs until now doesn't mean you'll be able to do so in a completely different and slower database. You could have fixed the slow queries with proper indexing, by using SNAPSHOT isolation, improving inefficient SQL or fixing unsuitable schemas

Comment: `I still need to find a way to read uncommitted data` why? Without that, it's impossible to answer. The data may not be there at all. Or you can fix the bad data code so you don't have to resort to dirty reads. If you thought of NOLOCK, have you realized it can result in *missing or duplicate* rows? In SQLite "dirty reads" will result in *missing rows"

Comment: Besides, you already set the `read_uncommitted` flag. What does `it still isn't working.` mean? Most likely this fails in SQLite in a different way than SQL Server - because it failed there as well. It will be worse in SQLite precisely because it's slower and hosted by your own application. The chance of encountering unexpected conditions will be higher

Comment: One example of bad coding is the SQL injection problem in all queries. In all cases a DbCommand is created with a vulnerable query instead of reusing the DbCommand with different parameters. That's both slow and insecure. Another problem, executing individual INSERTs - that's N times slower than executing an INSERT with N rows and certainly slower than batching N inserts and executing them.

Comment: I don't know any concrete case of why it needs to be done. I am doing research on SQLite for this possible migration. Whether it is right or wrong  I am looking for a way to achieve dirty reading. The SQLite documentations regarding isolation levels states that the only way to read uncommitted data is having a shared cache and read_uncommitted enabled. I did both of those and the select query isn't picking up the uncommitted data, it doesn't return any rows. This is just a test program, it is not production code.

Comment: Then don't read uncommitted data, especially if you don't know why you do it. ` I did both of..` trying random things to achieve something you don't understand isn't going to work. If you insist you needed dirty reads in SQL Server, you definitely didn't understand what's going on

Comment: Besides, again and AGAIN, why do you assume it didn't work? Why do you assume you aren't seeing how SQLite dirty reads work? What does `didn't work` even mean? You didn't see the missing data? You got blocked waiting for the exception to commit? You got duplicate rows? You got exceptions? All of these are *possible* symptoms. In SQL Server. It's worse in SQLite

Comment: When I execute the program it finishes without giving me any output. 'ExecuteScalar()' should return the first columns of the first row of the executed query. It is returning null, which leads me to believe the program isn't reading the uncommitted data. Why it is giving me this result I don't know, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: I read the SQLite documentation and tried implementing it. I have been looking into it for the past couple of days and cannot find a solution. I don't know why dity reading needs to be implemented and I don't need to know. I just need to know if it is possible and how to do it. I tried the above solution and it didn't work.

Comment: You can't find a solution if you can't even describe the problem. You describe what you assume the solution should look like. `I don't need to know.` you most definitely do. Otherwise just *don't do it*. There's a reason this simply isn't done in SQL Server or other databases. You only see this in SO questions asking "why doesn't this work?" or "Why did NOLOCK cause delays?"

Comment: `I just need to know if it is possible` what is the `it` you want? 1) How to read data that hasn't been committed yet? 2) How to avoid blocking? In the first case, in SQLite, it may not even be written yet. You can't read what doesn't exist yet. Commit the transaction instead. Long lived transactions are *bugs*. In the second case, you don't need it because SQLite effectively works the way SNAPSHOT ISOLATION would work. You don't need `read_uncommited` in this case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. I would like to know how read data that hasn't been committed yet. I would expect the above program to return the first column of the first row of the uncommitted data that has just been executed. It is not returning that, it is returning null. Did I implement it wrong? Am I getting something wrong? Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Looking at the documentation it should be possible.

Comment: I don't need to know why dirty reading needs to be implemented in the project. As of now the only thing I'm trying to do is read the few uncommitted rows that were executed in my program. For the sake of the argument let's say my context is this: I need a way to read 10 rows of uncommitted data using SQLite.

Comment: Then you're out of luck because you're already reading all there is to read. The entire logic is wrong no matter the database. People can't help more if you can't describe the problem. Dirty reads are the dirty hack to cover up the problem instead of solving it.

Comment: If you want a queue, use a queue. Don't try to use dirty reads as a surrogate for a queue. There are ways to use tables as queues but those require *extra locking*, not dirty reads. If you want two threads to communicate there are asynchronous pub/sub queues like Channel

Comment: But this is all there is to my problem. I want to read uncommitted data, this is my problem, the above is my solution but it is not working. I'm not trying to cover up any problems, I just want to test some of SQLite features for the sake of it. How would I go about reading uncommitted data in a .net application then?

Comment: You can't do that in SQLite.

Comment: I can't find anything explicit, but a lot of the wording about shared cache mode makes me think that it doesn't even work with WAL mode.

Comment: Upon further research it appears to me that `System.data.SQLite` doesn't support `ReadUncommitted` isolation level. I managed to achieve that using the Microsoft library, simply by starting the transaction as `connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)`. I find the documentation about the shared cache mode unclear. It states that it is obsolete and to use wal instead. However wal mode doesn't address the isolation level @ColonelThirtyTwo